# Asking questions involving algorithmic manipulation of photos

Tags: discussion

What brings me here is a long story of having my posts about algorithmic manipulation closed at a lot of programming sites on Stack network.

Basically, what I want to learn is the **fundamentals** that go behind various photo manipulation techniques. Like making them tinted, sepia-tone, etc.

I would like to ask if these questions will be considered on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer to what is on-topic is [in the help centre](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and I would be surprised if the wider community considered an algorithm to be on-topic.

With out knowing the exact question, it is difficult to answer; but if it was a fault with an implementation of an algorithm you've written, I would have thought [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) would be your friend.

Comment: Let's just say I post a question like "How do I manipulate the pixels to make them look sepia-tone ?" where I am expecting someone to say what values to change (no algorithms here, just the technique).. then is it on topic ??

Comment: That kinda sounds like you've got a general idea, but no algorithm or implementation, which is a bit awkward - this SE site would might be of help for doing it in a pre-existing program, but I don't think the wider community has the right expertise for helping you with the maths and algorithms involved, which isn't strictly photography.